# Do unit testing using protractor having good scope in future?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, protractor

I was working in Blackbox automation testing earlier, recently I am working on E2E unit testing using type script and Protractor framework. I just want to know the scope of my current work compared to my previous one. This ll help me to learn and work more enthusiastically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious about the term `E2E unit testing`? Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @demouser123 it's an End TO END testing for an Angular JS application, using Protractor (testing framework)

Comment: @PriyaDharshni that's the point. End to End Testing isn't Unit Testing by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you did e2e automation testing previously will surely help you in your e2e unit testing, as typescript, protractor and jasmine are widely use in frontend browser automation, as well as in unit tests.

You can unleash your knowledge of end 2 end testing in unit testing with the usage of assertion library Mocha and Chai.

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: Welcome, do let me know in case of any further concerns.